# Knockout .length or .count

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have some math that I need to do, I use razor to pull in all of these numbers in an array.  I don't count them right away cause I'll need to filter by them later.

I can get the array to print in my data-bind field but I can't add a .length or .count it doesn't work.  What am I doing wrong?

**Knockout**

```
<script>
    var thePage = function () {
        var self = this;
        self.All = ko.observableArray(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.All.Select(i => i.Number))));
        self.SomePercentage = ko.observable(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Percentage)));
        self.someTotal = ko.pureComputed(function () {
            var total = self.All // .length? .count? what goes here to count all the items I have in my array?!;
            return total;
        });
    };
    ko.applyBindings(new thePage());
</script>
```

Comment: try self.All().length

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`self.All` is an observable, you want the value of the observableArray, which is a Javascript Array:

```
 var total = self.All().length
```

KnockoutJs Observables/ObservableArrays are functions, Observables can take parameters, calling an observable with any parameters returns the Javascript primitive aka value of the Observable.

Answer (score 0):

To get the size of a JavaScript array, read the [`length` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length?v=control). Since `All` is an [observable](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html), you read the value by calling it as a function.

```
var total = self.All().length;
```